# How to make Views overlap each other by a specified amount?

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say I'm trying to stack cards, and I want to put a queen on top of a king, but still have the top 20 or so pixels of the king be visible so you can tell it's under the queen. How do you do this?

I've defined a grid layout, with linear layout containers. Each container contains one imagebutton. The closest I can get it is the encroaching imagebutton shrinks under the occupying imagebutton.

Like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/broaD.png

I would like to stack the imagebuttons, but still have the underlying imagebuttons still be clickable.

Edit: 
I was able to figure it out by extensive searching here and learning a lot about views. 
I'm now using

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -60);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"` for the top view so as to overlap the view below it. Here, *50dp* is the amount by which you want to overlap the views.

Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#0000ff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Through code:

```
ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) imageButton1
                .getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin,
                layoutParams.topMargin, layoutParams.rightMargin,
                (layoutParams.bottomMargin - 50));
        imageButton1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: I'm marking yours as correct. It's not exactly what I need, but seeing the margins modified in XML like in your answer would've caused me to go look for the Java way to do it.